# Dividing a set into 3 'unlabeled' subsets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So I have a problem from an old exam in my Discrete Mathematics-course where I come to a conclusion that feels logical enough for me, but it's not the correct one - please help me realize where I'm going wrong.

The problem is as follows;

```
In how many ways can the set {A,B,C,D,1,2,3,...,12} be divided into 3 'unlabeled' subsets
so that A and B are in different subsets and 1, 2 and 3 are in different subsets aswell?
```

The way I've thought it about is this;

```
1) Put 1, 2 and 3 into one subset each, making all the 3 subsets labeled. 
2) Find the total amount of combinations that are now available (not considering the first
constraint): 3^13 since all the 13 remaining objects can be placed in one of the three
subsets. 
3) Subtract the number of combinations in which A and B are in the same subset => I got this
to 3 * 3^11 since A and B can be put in any of the 3 subsets and then the remaining 11 
objects can be put in any of the 3 subsets.
4) Get the final answer 3^13 - 3 * 3^11 = 3^13 - 3^12.
```

However, the answer is supposed to be $6 * 3^{10} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the condition that $1,2$, and $3$ be in distinct subsets effectively labels the three subsets. There are then $3\cdot2=6$ ways to allocate $A$ and $B$ to distinct subsets. At this point $5$ of the $16$ items have been distributed, and each of the remaining $11$ can be put in any of the subsets, so I make it $6\cdot 3^{11}$, or $2\cdot 3^{12}$. This is the same as your answer of $3^{13}-3^{12}=(3-1)\cdot 3^{12}=2\cdot 3^{12}$, and by a different method as well. It appears to me that $6\cdot3^{10}$ is simply an error on someone’s part.

Comment: Oh yes, of course - that makes perfect sense. Must be an error in the answer suggestion then, thanks alot for the answer!

Comment: @NyfikenGul: You’re welcome!